# How can $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\lceil x\rceil\geq\lfloor y\rfloor\}$ be analytically characterized, if at all?

Tags: integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am interested in analytically characterizing $\Omega = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\lceil x\rceil\geq\lfloor y\rfloor\}.$ By "analytically characterize" I *actually* mean "Expressing $\Omega$ as a set -- or a (preferably finite) union/intersection of sets -- defined without using floor, ceiling, or integer/fractional part functions." (Apologies for the abuse of terminology.)

**Edit:** Clearly $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x-y>-1\}$ is a *proper* subset of $\Omega$. I think $\Omega\setminus A$ is some proper subset $B\subset\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: -1\leq x-y<2\}$; the challenging part for me is characterizing $B$.

Answer (score 4):

For $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, let $$A_z=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x>z-1\mbox{ and }y<z+1\}.$$ Note that we have $(x,y)\in A_z$ iff $\lceil x\rceil\ge z$ and $\lfloor y \rfloor\le z$. Consequently, we have $$(x,y)\in\Omega\iff (x,y)\in A_{\lfloor y\rfloor}\iff (x,y)\in A_{\lceil x\rceil}.$$ Consequently we can express $\Omega$ as a countable union of sets defined via simple inequalities: $$\Omega=\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}} A_z.$$

---

Interestingly, we can also prove a **negative** result relating to this question - namely, that $\Omega$ is not a [semialgebraic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set). This takes some work, however. *(More generally, $\Omega$ is not definable in any o-minimal structure on $\mathbb{R}$, but both "definable" and "o-minimal" are technically complicated notions.)*

Comment: In other words, it's a countable union of bottom-left quadrants.

Comment: @GregMartin *bottom-right

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\cos(\pi(x-y))= \cos(\pi(x+y))$$
holds when either
$$ \pi(x+y)-\pi(x-y)$$
or
$$ \pi(x+y)+\pi(x-y)$$
is a multiple of $2\pi$, i.e., when one of $x,y$ is $\in\Bbb Z$. One then quickly sees that
$$\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid \cos(\pi(x-y))\le \cos(\pi(x+y))\,\} $$
is a (closed) checkerboard pattern in the lattice grid.
If you cut this with the diagonal halfplane $$\{\,(x,y)\mid x-y\ge -2\,\}$$ and take the union with another diagonal half plane $$\{\,(x,y)\mid x-y\ge-1\,\},$$ you get exactly the  "zigzagged halfplane" we want. (You may need to adjust some translation perhaps - I didn't check).

Comment: Hi, I took the liberty of fixing up your sets.